# KnockoutJS. Bind data to 'select' without encoding (escaping)

Tags: knockout.js

I faced the problem, that the all elements which are bound to the select list are automatically encoded (or escaped).
I use the folowing scenario:

1. user clicks on the element from the multiselect;
2. text from the clicked options appears as the text input value (html input type = text);
3. this copied text value is encoded, because the text from the clicked option actually is encoded too; E.g. the input will contain the `N&amp;M` instead of `N&M`;

Is it possible to prevent the encoding, or maybe there are some workarounds ?

Thanks.

Comment: faced the same issue recently. Would like to have a solution too! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then yes, there is a way to setup the data binding of a `select` element so that the label and value properties are displayed the way you want it to.

To accomplish that, you have to pass the `optionsText` and `optionsValue` bindings a function, like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: list, 
                   optionsText: function(item) { return unescape(item); }, 
                   optionsValue: function(item) { return unescape(item); }, 
                   value: selectedOption"></select>
```

The `unescape` function should be one of your functions that cleans up the label and/or value of each item of the list. You could even make it cleaner by writing your function in your view model like this:

```
 optionsText: unescapeMyItem
```

... and then declaring in your view model:

```
this.unescapeMyItem = function(item) {
     return _.unescape(item); // your code to unescape the value
}
```

As for the unescape function, you can for example use [Underscore's unescape function](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) to perform this task.

I've [made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FKe3/1/) so you can see how it works (and I've used that Underscore function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very complete answer. I was hoping there was another solution, something without preprocessing for each item.

Comment: @SamousPrime thanks, glad to help. There could be another way, in writing a custom binding that extends the "options" binding, but you would have to put a lot of effort to it. And in the end, you would have to preprocess each item anyway unfortunately :-|